# Pentaho kittle - Create Zip file do not delete file

Tags: zip, pentaho, delete-file

I am facing issue using "Create Zip file component".

The zip component is expected to zip the Excel file getting processed in archive directory. Then delete the file in the processing directory.

It works fine for most of cases but gives some exceptions.

In few cases, it creates blank zip file and is unable to delete the file from processing folder.

It looks file the file gets somehow locked and it cannot be archived or deleted.

Please suggest solution. Pls find the image below that lists the flow and properties.

[Transformation flow and zip file properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hqv8d.jpg)

Thanks in Advance,
Rahul

Comment: The file is read by the transformation that is called from the same job. Is the transformation still locking the file in this case due to which it's not available for the Create Zip Task? In that case what is the best way to release the file in use in transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the file is still locked when it tries to be loaded from another step/transformation. You could use the **Check Files Locked** entry to be sure the file isn't locked when loaded in the next step.

I also suggesting reading [Pentaho's Wiki](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Check+Files+Locked) on the entry.

[image: Check files locked]